# Viewing deleted questions from the user profile

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, 10k-tools

I would like to verify claims like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1133286/find-the-remainder-when-5181-866332-is-divided-by-6#comment2313254_1133286) easily by going to a user's profile page and looking at the question list. The problem is, deleted questions aren't shown there. It might be helpful to include a view of the question list on a user profile wich also shows deleted questions. I can see a number of ways this can be useful

1. Suppose a user deletes his questions after they were answered to cover up trails. If this gets noticed on *one* instance, we can quickly find other questions possibly deleted for the same reason and re-open all of them without the risk of losing good answered questions
2. Behaviour like the one pointed out by amWhy in the linked comment can be verified and brought to moderator attention easier. (The moderators have such a feature, but this way they don't have to investigate false positives)

Is this possible?
Is there a way to find these wich I have just overlooked?
Do you agree?
Are there problems wich could arise from such a feature?

Comment: You know what would have brought the issue that amWhy brought up in her comment to the moderators' attention easier? If she (or _anyone else_) would have flagged the post for moderator attention. Moderators _can_ see deleted posts in user profiles, and can even search for them with a `deleted:yes` option.

Comment: @ArthurFischer I won't raise flags unless absolutely sure I can justify them. This is what I'm asking about. So is this `deleted:yes` available to 10k as well?

Comment: @AlexR It isn't. Moderator only.

Comment: @DanielFischer I would be curious to know why, [apparently a similar feature has existed but was removed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92979/restore-the-10k-ability-to-see-all-closed-deleted-posts-in-a-list)...

Comment: There is perhaps a fine line between giving too little information for the moderators to act on ("I think this might be plagiarised from somewhere") and putting too much onus on yourself to fully investigate before getting our attention. Personally, if an honest, clear and relatively focused flag is raised that regular users cannot act on, I'll almost certainly mark it as helpful regardless of whether I find anything in the end. I know that not all information is easily accessible to users, and expect that handling certain flags will require more effort on my part.

Comment: (Also, there's the [math mods' office](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/20352/math-mods-office) has been somewhat under-utilised lately.)

Comment: @ArthurFischer Okay, so an "I've seen this yesterday, but it seems to have been deleted and I can't find it." would be a helpful flag? If so, the feature-request remains (because I want to help you guys as much as possible, you are doing an awesome job and deserve the best possible assistance in that) but I'll change my flagging behaviour a little.

Comment: @AlexR The feature that had existed was not too similar, it was a list of _all_ deleted posts on the site which 10k users could access. That's quite a bit more to search than the list for a single user. It would still occasionally be useful, I guess. (And for the general flagging matters: what Arthur said.)

Comment: @AlexR: Most likely. If you knew where the old version was that would be very helpful, of course. Usually (nine times out of ten) if users are deleting closed/downvoted questions and re-asking them it's not too hard for us to discover this, but it's virtually impossible for us to be "on patrol" for this kind of behaviour. Directing us to (potentially) problematic situations is _helpful_.

Comment: Allright, thanks @*Fischer ;)

Comment: Let us define the following equivalence relation on the moderator: $X\sim Y$ if and only if they have the same surname. Then up to $\sim$ there is only one active moderator in this comment thread [as of writing this comment anyway].

Comment: It would -- at least in principle -- be a simple matter of programming to write a browser plugin that kept track of which questions by which users I've viewed in the last several days, and possibly even compared that with the user's currently visible questions. I don't see any rational reason why SE should force us to jump through that kind of hoops in order to recover information _that has already been in our possession once_.

Comment: It seems even to be allowed by the cc-by-sa conditions to write a third-party service that regularly polls SE for the latest questions and publishes a list of links to all questions per user, no matter whether they were subsequently deleted. (Essentially, Google does that, except there's no control on when it will recrawl a question and replace its remembered version with the this-question-has-been-deleted).